# Retrieve list of notifications received while app was in background

Tags: iphone, notifications, push-notification, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

Is there a way to know how many and what kind of local notifications were received when the application was in a background state?

Example:

- User closes app, app enters background state
- Notifications A, B, C, D and E are scheduled
- User receives notification A
- User receives notification B
- User receives notification C
- User reopens app
- App knows only notifications A, B and C were displayed

Comment: I know I can save the notification fire date and then check wether or not that date has passed, I'm looking for a more elegant solution, Thanks!

Comment: Your expectation of more "elegance" makes one wonder if you're not somehow imagining local notifications to be something that they are not. They are between the system and the user; once you've scheduled a local notification, it's out of your hands. If you're trying to solve a problem involving knowing that a certain time has passed, that's entirely up to you. - Note, however, that the shared application does tell you what local notifications have *not* yet fired (`scheduledLocalNotifications`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is really no callback if to your app if user presses **Cancel** button when notification fires. So there's no more elegante solution, i think.

Have been working on notifications too, and this problem made me crazy sometimes)